# Как выбрать товары с ценами с помощью WP_Query с ценами

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Как можно выбрать товары вместе с ценами, и нужно потом вернуть результат выборки по `ajax` допустим в массиве, для дальнейшей обработки товаров с помощью `js`.
Делал так:

```
$query = array(
    'post_type'      => array('product'),
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => POSTS_PER_PAGE,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
            'field'         => 'term_id',
            'terms'         => $currentCat,
            'operator'      => 'IN'
        ),
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_price',
            'value'   => $data['prices'],
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    )
);
if(!empty($_POST['ids'])){
    $query['post__not_in'] = $_POST['ids'];
}
$products = new WP_Query( 'cat=1&tag=apples' );
```

но возвращаются данные только из таблицы `wp_posts`.
Как это правильно сделать, чтобы в массиве были товары с ценами?

Comment: Какие данные в $data['prices']?

Comment: @noname228 это просто массив цен: ["11269","165993"]

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но это похоже та StdClass, а здесь нужен массив вида array($minRangePrice, $maxRangePrice)

Answer (score 2):

Поправь tax_query

```
   'tax_query'      => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
        'field'         => 'id',
        'terms'         => $currentCat,
    ),
```

Comment: подскажи, что должно быть в результирующем массиве? У меня всё-равно в массиве только данные из таблицы `wp_posts`. Можно ли вообще таким запросом WP_Query достать данные сразу из нескольких таблиц: `wp_posts` и `wp_postmeta`?

Comment: также нужны данные из таблицы `wp_terms`

Comment: @word Добавляй еще 1 запрос для получения термина. В результате у тебя должны быть только посты, которые относятся к таксономиям и с указаной метой

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь функцией wc_get_products( $args ); Он вернет Вам массив объектов WC_Product, там уже доставайте цену. Подробнее здесь https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query

Comment: а через ajax получится достать товары с помощью `wc_get_products`? `wc_get_products` что-то не работает.  `$products = wc_get_products( array('limit'=>3) );` - возвращает пустой массив,
`$products = new WP_Query( array('post_type'=>'product') );` возвращает содержимое `wp_posts`

Comment: через ajax не работает